# Execute remote bash with ssh together with a local script, that, when ends, will kill the remote execution

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, remote-access

I logged with ssh on the server with public key (no password). 
This are the command that I would like to automatize with a bash:

```
ssh user@ip
cd path
./bash0.sh parameter1 paramter2 & <-- this is a loop and is working on remote server in background
exit <-- exit form ssh

./bash1.sh <-- starting local bash
ssh user@ip pkill bash0.sh <-- kill the process at the end of the bash1.sh. From terminal is ok, but from bash?
```

The problem is to execute the `cd path` and immediately after the `./bash0.sh paramter1 parameter2 &` and then exit from ssh without waiting the `./bash0.sh` to finish. 
I cannot do `ssh user@ip ./path/bash0.sh paramter1 paramter2` because the bash file contains relative paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
ssh user@ip "cd path && ./bash0.sh parameter1 paramter2" &
/bash1.sh <-- starting local bash
ssh user@ip pkill bash0.sh
```

The "" are very important.

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach:

```
./bash1.sh && ssh user@ip pkill bash0.sh
```

Comment: `ssh user@ip pkill bash0.sh` seems to work, but I have start `./bash0.sh` correctly before test in a better way the kill of the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can send mutliple commands over ssh by seperating them with a semicolon:

```
ssh user@ip "cd path;./bash0.sh parameter1 parameter2 & exit"
```

(the `exit` is not needed but only there to show how to append more commands after the `&`)

And `ssh user@ip pkill bash0.sh` should work from a bash script. Your terminal is probably also just bash.

EDIT: See http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/executing-multiple-commands-a-bash-productivity-tip/ for a detailed explanation of the `;`, `&` and `&&` operator.

Comment: It does not work: file not found. I have tried to do `ssh user@ip cd path; ls`, but it shows the folder in the local path where I am in the terminal. The second command is execute locally not in ssh.